# How do I make a picture marker symbol at a given latitude and longitude in ArcGIS for Javascript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have no idea how to use ArcGIS, so I spent about six hours trying to figure it out and got nothing.

The only thing I have working is showing the map.

```
arcgisUtils.createMap("39526eb31f1d42359ab82894999ae6a3","map").then(function(response){
      //update the app 
      //dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
      //dom.byId("subtitle").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.snippet;

      var map = response.map;

      var graphicsLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();  
      map.addLayer(graphicsLayer);

      //test json
      json_object = {  
             "displayFieldName" : "STATE_FIPS",  
             "fieldAliases" : {  
               "STATE_FIPS" : "STATE_FIPS"  
             },  
             "geometryType" : "esriGeometryPoint",  
             "spatialReference" : {  
               "wkid" : 102100  
             },  
             "fields" : [  
               {  
                 "name" : "STATE_FIPS",  
                 "type" : "esriFieldTypeString",  
                 "alias" : "STATE_FIPS",  
                 "length" : 2  
               }  
             ],  
             "features" : [  
               {  
                 "attributes" : {  
            "STATE_FIPS" : "01"  
                 },  
                 "geometry" : {  
            "x" : -113.5781,  
            "y" : 37.0953  
                 }  
               }]};

      //end test json

      var point;  
      var symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol('img/Land/Lnd_icon_0.png', 200, 200);

      var graphic;

      for(var i=0; i<json_object.features.length; i++)  
         {  
          point = new esri.geometry.Point(json_object.features[i].geometry.x, json_object.features[i].geometry.y);  
          graphic = new esri.Graphic(point, symbol);  
          graphicsLayer.add(graphic);  

         }   

      //add the scalebar 
      var scalebar = new Scalebar({
        map: map,
        scalebarUnit: "english"
      });

      //add the legend. Note that we use the utility method getLegendLayers to get 
      //the layers to display in the legend from the createMap response.
      var legendLayers = arcgisUtils.getLegendLayers(response); 
      var legendDijit = new Legend({
        map: map,
        layerInfos: legendLayers
      },"legend");
      legendDijit.startup();
          dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', function(theMap) {   
          //resize the map when the browser resizes  
          dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', map,map.resize);  
        });   

      dojo.addOnLoad(init);  



    });
```

Comment: Please edit your original question with 1 question. I don't see a specific question. You do a good job of what you have. Just tell us what you need.

Comment: @BradNesom I edited it for clarity. Thanks for pointing that out. I was frustrated and not thinking clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code you supplied, nothing immediately obvious is jumping out as being wrong.  However, here are some tips to help further debug the problem:

- Try switching to a SimpleMarkerSymbol and see if this works to rule it out as being a problem with PictureMarkerSymbol.
- If it works and the issue is with PictureMarkerSymbol, user the browsers debug tools and check the URL it tries to get he image from is correct.  It might be returining a 404 due to the path being wrong.
- Use break points to check what's going on at various points.  If you aren't using an IDE such as Visual Studio you can just use the browsers built in dev tools: just add a line to the JavaScript code with `debugger;` where you want a break point.
- If even a SimpleMarkerSymbol doesn't work, it could be the geometry is wrong - maybe the spatial reference your coordinates are in is different to the one the map is using.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey. I got it working eventually. Thanks for taking your time to help me!